# K6 pass CA cert without password in http post request

Tags: javascript, x509certificate, k6

I am working on the load testing scenario where I need to pass the CA certificate in the post request. I am using K6 tool for the testing purpose using JavaScript.

The issue I am facing is that the CA certificate does not have any private key, and the only way I found from the documentation is using [SSL/TLS client certificates](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/protocols/ssl-tls/ssl-tls-client-certificates).

It takes 3 parameters

- Domain Name
- Cert File
- Key File

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHfeG.png)

I want to request an API and in its response I will be getting the certificate. Similarly another request will be send for its private key. But for that I need to pass a CA certificate with the request.

So, Is there any way to pass the certificate without having the key file in K6?

Comment: In fact, you need to pass client certificate, not CA certificate. If you have client certificate, then you certainly have private key.

Comment: @Crypt32 thankyou for the response. let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I want to hit a request to an API and in its response I will be getting the certificate. Similarly another request will be executed for its private key. But for that I need to pass a CA certificate with it. Hope I was able to explain the scenario.